# Error in find() Sails.js with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I have been working with Sails.js and MongoDB, but now I want to work with a SQL DB and I'm finding some problems which I can't solve.

I defined the model

**api/models/Carta.js**

```
module.exports.models = {


  connection:   "mysql",
  tableName:    "carta",

  attributes: {
    id              :   { type: 'int',    required: true, unique: true },
    a_categoria     :   { type: 'int',    required: true, unique: true },
    categoria       :   { type: 'string', required: true, unique: true },
  }
}
```

the connection

```
 mysql:  {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'maangatuts'
  }
```

Through MySQL WorkBench I created the DB "maangatuts"

```
CREATE TABLE `maangatuts`.`carta` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
 `a_categoria` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
 `categoria` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '');
```

and add 2 rows with data.

Until here everything would look right, but when in sails console I type:

```
Carta.find().exec(function(err,a){console.log(err)})
```

> Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error :
>   ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'carta.id' in 'field list'

Do you know what could be happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us your mysql table structure, or even better, the create table script fro your carta table?

Comment: Try: ` id : { columnName:'id', type: 'int', required: true, unique: true, primaryKey:true }`

Comment: that solve the error! =) thanks a lot! but I also included the columnName for 'categoria' and 'a_categoria' and sails doesn't show me that columns or even if I make a Carta.create() both columns won't write in the DB

Comment: Try this commands: `npm uninstall sails-mysql
npm cache clear
npm install sails-mysql`

Comment: I did, and the other columns don't appear yet